# ASP.NET Core 5.0 application using React.js and MySQL as Database

Tags: mysql, reactjs, mysql-connector, asp.net-core-5.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

Recently I am trying new ASP.NET Core 5.0 with React.js. I want to use MySql as my database server.

Now here I want to use ASP.NET Identity Server for Membership which we previously had in ASP.NET versions.

I tried to follow a tutorial listed over here: [Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4I0DUw6C84)

Now in appsettings.json here is the code

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost; port=3306; database=trom; user=root; password=hello@world; CharSet=utf-8"
  },
  "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "Trom": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  },
"AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Now in the Startup.cs I am trying to make changes as suggested in video

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Trom.Data;
using Trom.Models;

namespace Trom
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseMySql(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is

[image: Image of Error I am getting]

There are many ways suggested on documentation website. But nothing seems to be working out. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

The video is a bit older and uses a Pomelo version for EF Core 3.0.

For 5.0, take a look at the [sample code](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#2-services-configuration) that we show on our [repository](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) home page:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Replace with your connection string.
        var connectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;password=1234;database=ef";

        // Replace with your server version and type.
        // Use 'MariaDbServerVersion' for MariaDB.
        // Alternatively, use 'ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)'.
        // For common usages, see pull request #1233.
        var serverVersion = new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 26));

        // Replace 'YourDbContext' with the name of your own DbContext derived class.
        services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(
            dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions
                .UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion)
                // The following three options help with debugging, but should
                // be changed or removed for production.
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information);
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors()
        );
    }
}
```

For your posted code above, this translates to:

```cs
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
var serverVersion = ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString);

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion));
```

We added a mandatory `ServerVersion` parameter to the `UseMySql()` method in 5.0, because Pomelo will make use of newer features, depending on the MySQL/MariaDB version you are using.